# Eliminate column from table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to automatically eliminate a column from a `html` table using `javascript`. The table is created automatically from a `csv` file using a framework so I can't modify it (ex. add an `id`, etc.). I managed to eliminate the column by adding a link to the column header, and on click it eliminates the column, but I can't find a way to do it automatically when the page loads. I'm new to `javascript` so please try to explain it for dummies.

```js
function closestByTagName(el, tagName) {
  while (el.tagName != tagName) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (!el) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return el;
}

function delColumn(link) {
  var idx = 2,
      table = closestByTagName(link, "TABLE"),
      rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    table.rows[i].deleteCell(idx);
  }

  return false;
}

window.onload = function() {
  var th = document.querySelectorAll("th");
  th[2].innerHTML += ' <a href="#" onclick="return delColumn(this)">X</a>';
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table class="inline">
    <tr class="row0">
      <th class="col0">FullName</th>
      <th class="col1">Country</th>
      <th class="col2">Position</th>
      <th class="col3">CellPhone</th>
      <th class="col4">Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row1">
      <td class="col0">magnus</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">22</td>
      <td class="col4">magnus.gaylord@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
      <td class="col0">Phoebe Feest</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">23</td>
      <td class="col4">ylittel@example.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row3">
      <td class="col0">Prof. Tad Johnston</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">24</td>
      <td class="col4">srau@example.org</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row4">
      <td class="col0">Annabelle Ortiz</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">25</td>
      <td class="col4">damore.walker@example.org</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row5">
      <td class="col0">Mrs. Adella Schiller IV</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">26</td>
      <td class="col4">jadyn.dibbert@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The above code works but I have to press the `x` on the position column for it to be eliminated and I need it to happen automatically. In other words I don't want to use the code `href="#" onclick="return delColumn(this)"` but have it happen on load.

Comment: Have you tried calling *delColumn* directly from the load event? E.g. `delColumn(document.querySelectorAll("th")[2])`?

Comment: works like a charm, thankyou very much!!!!!

Comment: Since all your columns have a particular class, maybe you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".col2").forEach(node => node.remove());`

Comment: @Shidersz wow I was triyng to solve this the whole day and you managed to do it in like a minute and one line!!!! thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your columns have a particular `class`, maybe one possible solution using `ES6` is to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".col2").forEach(col => col.remove());
```

Or with a standard approach:

```
var cols = document.querySelectorAll(".col2");

for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
{
    cols[i].remove();
}
```

## Example:

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    var cols = document.querySelectorAll(".col2");

    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
    {
        cols[i].remove();
    }

    // Or with ES6:
    //document.querySelectorAll(".col2").forEach(col => col.remove());
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table class="inline">
    <tr class="row0">
      <th class="col0">FullName</th>
      <th class="col1">Country</th>
      <th class="col2">Position</th>
      <th class="col3">CellPhone</th>
      <th class="col4">Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row1">
      <td class="col0">magnus</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">22</td>
      <td class="col4">magnus.gaylord@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
      <td class="col0">Phoebe Feest</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">23</td>
      <td class="col4">ylittel@example.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row3">
      <td class="col0">Prof. Tad Johnston</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">24</td>
      <td class="col4">srau@example.org</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row4">
      <td class="col0">Annabelle Ortiz</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">25</td>
      <td class="col4">damore.walker@example.org</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row5">
      <td class="col0">Mrs. Adella Schiller IV</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">26</td>
      <td class="col4">jadyn.dibbert@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shidersz's answer is fine, but it's also worth noting that you could do with with a single CSS rule instead of JavaScript:

```css
.col2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table class="inline">
    <tr class="row0">
      <th class="col0">FullName</th>
      <th class="col1">Country</th>
      <th class="col2">Position</th>
      <th class="col3">CellPhone</th>
      <th class="col4">Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row1">
      <td class="col0">magnus</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">22</td>
      <td class="col4">magnus.gaylord@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
      <td class="col0">Phoebe Feest</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">23</td>
      <td class="col4">ylittel@example.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row3">
      <td class="col0">Prof. Tad Johnston</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">24</td>
      <td class="col4">srau@example.org</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row4">
      <td class="col0">Annabelle Ortiz</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">25</td>
      <td class="col4">damore.walker@example.org</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row5">
      <td class="col0">Mrs. Adella Schiller IV</td>
      <td class="col1">Guatemala</td>
      <td class="col2">Lacayo</td>
      <td class="col3">26</td>
      <td class="col4">jadyn.dibbert@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As the question specifically requests javascript, seems like this might be better as a comment rather than an answer....

Comment: This is a good alternative too, the only note about this is that the DOM elements will still exists in the table, but if the goal is just to not visually show the data, it is nice. +1

Comment: @Jordan Running Thanks I would have used this but I couldn't have the elements in the DOM as  Shidersz mentioned. Regardless it is a really good answer. +1